# Jersey HTTP POST AsyncResponse handler with raw bytes body

Tags: java, post, asynchronous, jersey-2.0

How do I get access to the raw bytes of my HTTP POST body when I want to use the AsyncResponse to send a response back at a later time?

In the code below, when I uncomment this part `/*, @Context final byte [] rawBytesIn*/`, I get the following error: ERROR [2015-05-20 22:36:18,441] com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.abc.resources.MyResource.postSearch(javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse,byte[]) at parameter at index 0
  SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public void com.abc.resources.MyResource.postSearch(javax.ws.rs.container.AsyncResponse,byte[]) at parameter at index 1

```
@Path("/")
public class MyResource
{
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/fastinfoset")
    @Produces("application/fastinfoset")
    public void postSearch(@Suspended final AsyncResponse ar/*, @Context final byte [] rawBytesIn*/) {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                byte [] rawBytesOut = ProcessRequest(rawBytesIn);
                ar.resume(rawBytesOut);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you need the `@Context` annotation? The request body doesn't need any annotation (and actually _should not_ have one)

Comment: if you change the @Consumes to text and the method to `public void postSearch(final String text, @Suspended final AsyncResponse ar)` is it working?

Comment: or use `public void postSearch(@Suspended final AsyncResponse ar, @Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest)`